# How do I find usages of methods and properties?

Tags: php, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3 and I'm trying to find usages of methods and/or properties within my project.  I seem to remember being able to do this in Zend Studio, and I wonder if there's an equivalent or a plugin that I'm just not finding.  I search around for this and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
Ctrl+Alt+G
```

It just does a general search on selected term but is better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the 'outline' feature?

See `Window > Show View > Other... > General > Outline`

Comment: No, that's just the opposite.  The outline shows where methods and properties are defined.  I want to see where they are used.  One could search for them, but find usages is generally a little smarter than a search.

Comment: In 'normal' Eclipse there is the Feature **Call Hierarchy**. 

Sadly there is no Hierarchy View in Aptana, instead of for PyDev. 

In Eclipse i have following possibilities:
http://d.pr/i/ZW1W

Hope that´s what you searched for